# About the various ensembles in Thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, partition-function

The properties of a system in thermodynamical equilibrium are described by a partition function:
$$
\mathcal{Z} = \text{Tr} \ e^{-\beta E} = \sum_n e^{-\beta E_n} 
$$
This defines so called canonical ensemble. When we have several conserved quantities - particle number $N$, angular momentum $J$, ... , one can define grand-canonical ensemble:
$$
\mathcal{Z} = \text{Tr} \ e^{-\beta (E - \mu N - \Omega J)}
$$
Where $\mu$ is chemical potential, $\Omega$ is angular velocity. This construction is valid for other kinds of conserved charges with corresponing "chemical potentials".

Energy is a conserved charge with respect to translations of time $t \rightarrow t + a$. Angular momentum is a conserved charge with the respect of rotations about given axis $\phi \rightarrow \phi + a$. And $E - \Omega J$ can be considered as a new Hamiltonian with respect to the combined translation and rotation - $i (\partial_t + \Omega \partial_\phi)$. So the canonical ensemble in terms of $E - \Omega J$ and grand-canonical ensemble written in the initially conserved quantities define the same system.

Now let us consider the system on some background with several Killing vector fields. To each of these corresponds some conserved quantity, which can be regarded as some "generalized" Hamiltonian. What sense can be given to the partition function, where instead of energy there sits some other conserved quantity, for instance :
$$
\mathcal{Z} = \text{Tr} \ e^{-\Omega J} 
$$
or any other conserved charge?

In addition, time translations $\partial_t$ and rotations $\partial_\phi$ are the choices of particular vector fields on some manifold. Is there some construction or entity above the partition function, which by choice of some vector field reduces to a particular canonical ensemble?

Sorry for being rather messy. I would be grateful for any comments and remarks